# Google photos uploads everything from DCIM folder

Tags: google-photos, google-backup, redmi

So in my Redmi Note 7 Pro, the screenshots and screen recordings all go in a subfolder inside DCIM folder. Photos (app by Google) simply uploads everything in the DCIM folder. I have tried [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/199737/107756), but it did not work (hence asking a new question).

Comment: You should be able to configure the folders you want to sync: https://www.androidcentral.com/how-set-google-photos

Comment: It doesn't contain DCIM folder (and DCIM subfolders).

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be *no* clear solution to this.

I have had to manually move the sub folders within DCIM to outside the DCIM folder using a file explorer so that I can later individually choose which folders should get backed up in Google Photos.

Answer (score 0):

```
- Settings
- Backup & Restore
- Select Account
- Unselect Sync Photos
```

Now in each app...

- Open Photos ( The app by Google )
- Go into settings
- locate sync or Save Storage features
- Disable sync

Look around for any other apps using synchronization and disable it...

I think Google Drive does this for Photos as well as other apps.